# Bulk refactoring function call with extra arguments and changed function name

Tags: regex, bash

In a folder I need to recursively change all function calls like

```
$this->ts("couldbeanystring") 
/* should now be: */ 
$this->translate("couldbeanystring", [], "admin")
```

in every .php file. I can do it from bash, phpstorm, any way. Thank you!

Comment: So what is the coding problem here? You only described the task.

Comment: There are more than 100 occurrences and I need a shell script (or just one command) to not have to manually change them all. I am not very good at regex and I could not find any answer here on stackoverflow

Comment: But you surely tried something, right? Please let us know what way to help you, share your attempts.

Comment: \$this\-\>ts\([\"|\']([a-zA-Z\.])+[\"|\'] finds the occurrences, but how should the replacement regex look like?

Comment: Is that in PHPStorm? Try `(\$this->)ts\(((["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\4.)*?)(\3\))` => `$1translate($2$3, [], "admin")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFXZxu/1).

Comment: If possible, consider changing object '$this' to have a method ts. It will be significantly less work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution with sed:

```
sed -e 's/$this->ts(\("[^"]*"\)/$this->translate(\1, [], "admin")/'
```

It create single capture group, for whatever parameter to ts, and build the new call from \1

Comment: With SED, the '$' is the end of string, only at the end of the pattern. It will need to be escaped only if when searching '$' at the end of the line. You can capture '$X' with this pattern '$X'.